# Latest date occurence for a given month and day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the best way to get the last occurrence of a date having the given month and day with Ruby/Rails. The Returned value should be a Date object.

i.e.:

prev_occuring(month, day)

```
today = Date.today               # => Thu, 14 Dec 2019
today.prev_occurring(:june, 1)   # => Sat, 1 Jun 2019

or 

today = Date.today               # => Thu, 9 Jan 2020
today.prev_occurring(:june, 1)   # => Sat, 1 Jun 2019
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What is the expected output you are looking for?  `prev_occorring` take a weekday argument [see method definition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_and_time/calculations.rb#L329)

Comment: Using the same name as the already existing prev_occuring method maybe mislead you. This new method should takes a month and a day as argument and return a full date like in my example, this date should be the latest occurence of a date with the given month and day.

Comment: have you tried anything? personally I wouldn't money patch the Date class to add the method. This should be really simple: just create a date object with that month and day and use the year from your current date, if it's > than the current date then substract 1 to the year.

Comment: "latest" is vague. Do you mean the "last" occurrence of a date having the given month and day (i.e, the latest previous date having the given month and day)? Moreover, do you want a `Date` object returned? In any even, when clarifying a question please edit the question rather than doing it in comments (which may not be noticed by some readers).

Comment: If you clarify your question with an edit it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one way to do it, of course.

But here's one approach:

```
$> Date.parse('28 dec').then { |date| date.advance(years: (date > Date.today ? -1 : 0)) }
=> Fri, 28 Dec 2018
$> Date.parse('3 feb').then { |date| date.advance(years: (date > Date.today ? -1 : 0)) }
=> Sun, 03 Feb 2019
```

Alternatively, you could opt to be more explicit (i.e. not rely on `Date.parse` magic)...

You could use `Date::MONTHNAMES` to fetch the month number, and then write a little conditional to check whether the given date falls after the current date, in a calendar year.

It would then probably be easiest to just use `Date.new` with the year/month/day values, rather than `Date#advance`.

Comment: This method seems to work without `.then` in older ruby versions i.e. 2.4.1..  While version 2.6+ supports `.then` which is alias of `yield_self`   add in version 2.5, how does `Date.parse` magically allow the yield block without using either, which might be good for backward compatibility?

Comment: @lacostenycoder This method does not work without `then`. `Date.parse` does not yield a block; writing this without `then` is equivalent to just writing e.g. `Date.parse('28 dec')` and completely ignoring the "maybe go back a year" part of the logic, which was fundamental to the question.

Comment: If you want to make this code backwards compatible (or even, just compatible with older ruby versions), then you could write it as two lines rather than one: `date = Date.parse('28 dec'); date.advance(years: (date > Date.today ? -1 : 0))`. I was just taking advantage of the newish ruby method to fit it more concisely into a single line. (However, there was also no mention in the original question about needing a solution which ran on an old ruby version.)

Answer (score 2):

I understand that, given a month expressed as a symbol and a day of that month, the requirement is to return a date object that represents the last date that has the given month and day that is no later than the current date. Here is a pure-Ruby solution.

```
require 'date'
```

```
def last_date(month, day)
  date_this_year = Date.strptime("%s%s" % [month.to_s.capitalize, day], '%B%d')
  date_this_year <= Date.today ? date_this_year : date_this_year << 12
end
```

See [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and [Date#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C).

```
last_date(:june, 1)
  #=> #<Date: 2019-06-01 ((2458636j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
last_date(:december, 23)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-12-23 ((2458476j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

One could alternatively write:

```
def last_date(month, day)
  today = Date.today
  date_this_year = Date.new(today.year,
    Date::MONTHNAMES.index(month.to_s.capitalize), day)
  date_this_year <= today ? date_this_year : date_this_year << 12
end
```

See [Date::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new).

Comment: 29 February is a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: 29 February is a bit of a nuisance.